# Eclipse - How can I launch the build process programatically?

Tags: eclipse, build-process

I was wondering if it's a at all possible to run the eclipse build process for a particular project using code? I have searched stackoverflow and can't seem to find an answer to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the code of `org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.dialogs.CleanDialog.buttonPressed(...)`.

Comment: I can't seem to find the 'CleanDialog' class within the eclipse api documentation here - http://help.eclipse.org/help33/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/index.html Have you got a link to this? Also, how will this help me?

Comment: That's because it's an internal class, and internal classes in Eclipse aren't part of the API, so there's no documentation for this. Get the source code for Eclipse UI (or the Eclipse for RCP developers package, sourcecode is included there). It will help you in that way, that you can use the code there as a template to develop your own plugin for your needs

Comment: @Joeblackdev sorry for the confusion... Basically you need to create a `BuildAction` object (which is public API) that returns the resources you want to build and invoke `runInBackground(...)` on this... The details are best lifted from `org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.dialogs.CleanDialog`...